# External hard disk drive icons broken on Big Sur

Tags: finder, hard-drive, icon, big-sur

Since I upgraded from Catalina to Big Sur, Finder no longer shows proper disk icons in the sidebar for my external drives. Instead, they all have generic file icons.

This applies to a disk I have formatted under Catalina as well as for my TimeMachine disk that I reformatted with APFS under Big Sur.

[image: External disks in Finder sidebar]

Is there a way to make Finder re-generate the icons? Or is this a general bug?

Comment: I'm finding the same problem, and it includes additional drives (i.e. internal drives), network drives/servers (both AFP, SMB, etc), Google Drive (Google Drive "File Stream"), and other mounted drives (i.e. using Expandrive).

Super frustrating!